# Is there a way to find out if a non-Android Bluetooth device is connected to my Android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have an android phone and a non-android device like a bluetooth dialer with me.

As Far As I Know

With listeners like `ACL_CONNECTED` we can catch connecting of a bluetooth device if it's connecting while application is running.

But is there any way to know if a device is connected to phone before the app is started and my app can connect through it?

In Other Words

will I recieve `ACL_CONNECTED` or other recievers if the device is already connected before I start my application?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to receive the Broadcast or do  you want to connect to a device?
For the broadcast, you can register a BroadcastReceiver that tells you, that any device is connected (or connecting if you want to) to your phone

Comment: I want to use my audio dialer with the app, will I recieve ACL_CONNECTED or other recievers if the device is already connected before I start my application?

Comment: Ah I see what your point is. I have had a similar problem, I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the Broadcast when a device is connected and a `SharedPreference` to store a value like a Boolean.

This could be a code for the Receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().contentEquals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED")) {
         //DO SOMETHING, like using a SharedPreference
    } else {
        if (intent.getAction().contentEquals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT")) {
         //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

You should also start a service once the device is connected, that watches if Bluetooth is turned off and then sets the `SharedPreference` to false, as you would not receive a `ACL_DISCONNECT` Broadcast.

That could look like this:

```
public class BTService extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
        filter2.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(rec_bt_change, filter2);
}




private final BroadcastReceiver rec_bt_change = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
            //SettingsClass.log_me(tag, "BT turned off, stopping");
            //DO SOMETHING
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I think something is complicated here, first of all ACL_CONNECTED is not received while device is already paired and connected.... to received an ACL_CONNECTED broadcast we need to re-connect the device after app's first run..... I am receiving `android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED` with extra 0, which shows `SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED` if compared to AudioManager constants

Comment: Yes, you need to install the app before connecting the BT device.

Comment: Like I said, you need to *install* the app first. After disconnecting the BT device or rebooting your phone, you will always know